# Memory allocation and sharing of the reference that is passed to the classes in Java

Tags: java

I am confused with the memory allocation of references in Java when you pass them to the methods in Java. As a Test I did an example as below,

```
class Store{
public int[] buffer = new int[5];
 }

class ConsumeStore{
Store store;
public ConsumeStore(Store store){
    this.store = store; 
}

public int useStore(){
    return store.buffer[0];
}
  }

class ProduceStore{
Store store;
public ProduceStore(Store store){
    this.store = store;
}

public void putStore(){
    store.buffer[0] = 100;
}
 }

public class CheckRef {
  public static void main(String args[]){
  Store store = new Store();
  ConsumeStore consStore = new ConsumeStore(store);
  ProduceStore prodStore = new ProduceStore(store);
  prodStore.putStore();
  System.out.println(consStore.useStore());   
   }
 }
```

Well the output is 100.

Here I am passing the Store reference to ProducerStore. Inside ProducerStore I am assigning it to the class member of it. I am doing the same for ConsumerStore as well.

Could someone explain me how the memory allocation is done for Store referece and how it shared among the ProducerStore and ConsumerStore?

Comment: We are also. Why do you use a public variable at first place?   Then you are passing same reference which means both objects will have same reference so modification will be applicable for both objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your `ProducerStore` and `ConsumerStore` have a reference to the same object `store`, that you passed to each one.

So when you modify `store` internal state (its `buffer` member), either externally or in any of the Producer/Consumer, all the classes that have reference to it are "updated" because they don't hold a distinct value, they only hold a reference to the unique value `store`.

**Something different** would happen if you reallocated the object entirely. For example:

```
public void putStore(){
    store = new Store()
    store.buffer[0] = 100
}
```

In this case, the Consumer and the Producer would have a different store: Consumer would still have a reference to the original store, while Producer would have the new one defined within the Put method.

You can think of it as: everytime you do a `new`, a new object is created in memory. Then when you pass it around to classes, everyone only has reference to that unique object.

Answer (score 1):

You need two separate instances.If you pass the same reference then any change will get reflected on both objects since they are pointing to same reference.

```
Store store = new Store();
ConsumeStore consStore = new ConsumeStore(store);
Store anotherStore = new Store();
ProduceStore prodStore = new ProduceStore(anotherStore);
```

Few notes

- Never use public variables.
- Use inheritance if your design demands for it

You should read  [Lesson: Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/)

Comment: I would argue that (but that's my opinion) if your design demands for inheritance, then your design is crap. Change it. Inheritance is evil. Use composition. Anyway, slightly off-topic :)

Comment: @Guillaume Everything has its own advantage and disadvantages :)